# Unable to connect to Postgres from inside Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, apache-superset

I have a bunch of Docker containers (which in fact is [Apache Superset](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset) system). I run them using docker-compose, like so:

```
$ docker-compose run
```

The [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file can be taken from official Apache Superset repo. The problem is - I can not create new database connection to my Postgresql database running on the same host where dockerized Apache Superset is running. I can connect to Postgresql from wherever I like. On the host machine I can connect to it from Python, using both 127.0.0.1 address and 192.X.X.X address. But Apache Superset container can not establish connection to this Postgres instances - I tried both 127.0.0.1 and 192.X.X.X - and they are both not working.

When I enter the superset Docker container shell, I can check all relevant IP addresses:

```
superset@2cf0e6dde567:/app$ ip addr show eth0
48: eth0@if49: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
link/ether 02:42:ac:12:00:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
inet 172.18.0.6/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

So, it seems like my superset Docker container has 172.18.0.6 address. I also check this:

```
superset@2cf0e6dde567:/app$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.18.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

So, if I'm not mistaken my host address where Postgres is running can be reached using this ip address - `172.18.0.1`. I check it with `ping` and see that it's ok:

```
$ ping 172.18.0.1
PING 172.18.0.1 (172.18.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.103 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
```

But still I can not connect to Postgres using this IP address. Probably, I need to configure Postgresql itself, but I do not know how. My pg_hba.conf looks like so:

```
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

And my postgresql.conf contains:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Probably, I'm still missing something. How can I fix it?

PS.

This is what I tried inside superset container in Python shell:

```
import psycopg2
import sqlalchemy as db

#engine = db.create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@192.168.234.137:5433/test')
#engine = db.create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5433/test')
engine = db.create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@172.18.0.1:5433/test')
cnx = engine.connect()
```

I tried all possible ips: 192.168.234.137 (my host machine ip), 127.0.0.1 and 172.18.0.1. None of them works. I just get an error message from Python:

```
No route to host
    Is the server running on host "X.X.X.X" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
```

where X.X.X.X is one of 192.168.234.137, 127.0.0.1 and 172.18.0.1

Comment: I know about this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach . But as you can see, it does not help 172.X.X.X address is reachable from Docker, but database connection still can not be established

Comment: And If I simply add `network_mode: host` to the official docker-compose.yml, it crashes everything. So, I would rather fix this problem, without tweaking any code in the repository.

Comment: According to the docker-compose.yml you linked, it listens on localhost. From the same host, can you connect to it on host 127.0.0.1, port 5432?

Comment: @Robert Seaman. On my host machine Postgres is running at port 5433 in order not to conflict with Apache Superset own Postgres container. And I can not establish connection to my Postgres instance, using host 127.0.0.1, port 5433. I will attach serevral screenshots

Comment: How did you configure postgres to run on 5433? Are you not using the docker-compose.yml you linked?

Comment: I'm using the default Dockerized postgres. I just do not change the default docker-compose.yml file. But on my host machine I have another Postgres instance running at port 5433, and it is absolutely ok. I can connect to it from wherever I like. I configured it with `port = 5433` in postgresql.conf file.

Comment: And what I want is to create a new datasource in Apache Superset. To do this I need to supply it with ip, port and etc. of my Postgres instance running on the host machine

Comment: try put in docker-compose.yml before any image configuration
`networks: <network_name>: driver: bridge`

this instruction will create a new bridge network, then you put it in each image you want to run it on this network, like this:
`superset-worker:  networks: <network_name>  build: *superset-build`

hope this will help you

Comment: @alim91. Thanks! Can you make a formated answer from this comment? And I will check it

Answer (score 1):

in docker-compose.yml put before any image configuration instruction:

```
networks:
    <network_name>:
        driver: bridge
```

then put `networks: <network_name>` instruction in any image you want to run it on this network, like this:

```
superset-worker:
    networks: 
        - <network_name> 
    build: *superset-build
```

Comment: It does not work. I get `ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: services.db.networks contains an invalid type, it should be an array, or an object`. Probably, I do something wrong.

Comment: make sure you put the first network instruction outside services and at the same level of indent, and I did edit my answer, for the image service, the network name should be on a new line, my bad.

Comment: . plus <network_name> is a place holder, so you can write anything name you want without <> symbols

Comment: I checked it. It did not help. I checked even connection to dockerized Postgres, running through the same `docker-compose up` command. I can connect it only using service name `db`. I tried 127.0.0.1 and it does not work.

Comment: did you put **networks** instruction in **db** service?

Comment: I put it to all services, including db service

Comment: did you put double quotes to **network name** and **depends_on**? if you can post the docker-compose.yml file would be better?

Comment: In fact, you can easily reproduce the whole problem. Just clone the official repo, make sure that you have enough RAM, then run it with docker-compose and try to connect to Postgresql instance running on host from `superset`container.

Comment: I did not put any dooble quotes and I'm not using `depends_on` construct.I just added what you adviced to add.

Comment: networks:
  test_network:
    driver: bridge - it looks like this with necessary indenting

Answer (score 1):

In your docker-compose.yml add "extra_hosts" field like this:

```
version: "3.7"
  services:
    backend:
      build: .
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      extra_hosts:
        - "pghost:172.18.0.1"
```

and in your code, you should use "pghost" to connect your postgresql server like this:

```
engine = db.create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@pghost:5433/test'
```