# host.docker.internal will not resolve in docker-compose

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

So I have a .NET solution with two projects. These work fine when running with `dotnet run`, but I'm having issues with my docker compose. When adding env variables with url paths to talk between containers, i generally use something like `host.docker.internal` to resolve the path to the other container, but for some reason that doesn't resolve and just gets used as, for instance, `https://host.docker.internal:49833/connect/authorize` instead of `https://localhost:49833/connect/authorize`.

This doesn't make sense to me as i literally have another project on my machine that runs with this setup just fine. what am i missing?

project 1 has a dockerfile like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ["RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/RecipeManagement.csproj", "./RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/"]
#COPY ["SharedKernel/SharedKernel.csproj", "./SharedKernel/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/RecipeManagement.csproj"

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet build "RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/RecipeManagement.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build-env AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/RecipeManagement.csproj" -c Release -o /app/out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/out .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/RecipeManagement.dll"]
```

project 2 has a dockerfile like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
RUN apt install -y nodejs

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ["AuthServerWithDomain/AuthServerWithDomain.csproj", "./AuthServerWithDomain/"]
#COPY ["SharedKernel/SharedKernel.csproj", "./SharedKernel/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./AuthServerWithDomain/AuthServerWithDomain.csproj"

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet build "AuthServerWithDomain/AuthServerWithDomain.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build-env AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "AuthServerWithDomain/AuthServerWithDomain.csproj" -c Release -o /app/out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/out .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/AuthServerWithDomain.dll"]
```

and the compose looks like this:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  recipemanagement-db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '63230:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: dev_recipemanagement
    volumes:
      - recipemanagement-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  recipemanagement-api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: RecipeManagement/src/RecipeManagement/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "63231:8080"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "Development"
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: https://+:8080;
      ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path: "/https/aspnetappcert.pfx"
      ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password: "password"
      DB_CONNECTION_STRING: "Host=recipemanagement-db;Port=5432;Database=dev_recipemanagement;Username=postgres;Password=postgres"
      "AUTH_AUDIENCE": "recipe_management"
      "AUTH_AUTHORITY": "https://host.docker.internal:49833"
#      ^^^^^^^^^^^ not sure why this and the below don't resolve *************************************************************************
      "AUTH_AUTHORIZATION_URL": "https://host.docker.internal:49833/connect/authorize"
      "AUTH_TOKEN_URL": "https://host.docker.internal:49833/connect/token"
      "AUTH_CLIENT_ID": "recipe_management.swagger"
      "AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET": "974d6f71-d41b-4601-9a7a-a33081f80687"
      "RMQ_HOST": "localhost:TBDRMQPORT"
      "RMQ_VIRTUAL_HOST": "/"
      "RMQ_USERNAME": "guest"
      "RMQ_PASSWORD": "guest"

    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
      
  recipemanagement-authserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: AuthServerWithDomain/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "49833:8080"
    environment:
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: "https://+:8080;"
      ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path: "/https/aspnetappcert.pfx"
      ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password: "password"

    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
        
volumes:
  recipemanagement-data:
```

Comment: Related: [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24319662/711006) Adding `extra_hosts:` to my `docker-compose.yml` helped me.

Answer (score 4):

See @DavidMaze comment. Best to search on [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) as the starting point.

(The Dockerfile's should be irrelevant to your question.)
There are a couple of options, with trial and error to get the exact behavior you want. I'd encourage you to find better explanations on the following suggestions:

In your compose file, at the 'service' level, you can add [extra_hosts](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#extra_hosts)

```
my-service:
  extra_hosts:
    host.docker.internal:host-gateway
    #host.docker.internal:127.0.0.1 for linux
```

But when using `compose`, a better option is to have docker create a network specific to your containers with
`docker network create --driver bridge my_recipe_ntwk`

and then at the top level of your compose:

```
services:
volumes:
networks:
  my-private-ntwk:
    external:
      name: my_recipe_ntwk
```

and then at the 'service' level

```
my-service-1:
  networks:
    - my-private-ntwk

my-service-2:
  networks:
    - my-private-ntwk
```

For postgres running on the host, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60750495/458354) and there should be a few other similar answers.

I believe if all services are configured on the same bridge network, you actually use the service name, e.g. `my-service-1:8080` and don't inclue the `https`. I might be wrong. (In my case, my containers connect to Postgres on the host itself, and that requries 'extra_hosts' and it's own special workaround.) You are hosting a Postgres container, so I believe your connection host and port, when using the bridge network, would simply be `my-private-ntwk:5432`

Comment: interesting, i'll give this a try. how would i set the env var links to use this network? just put something like `https://my_recipe_ntwk:5432`?

Comment: I believe if all services are configured on the same bridge network, you actually use the service name, e.g. `my-service-1:8080` and don't inclue the `https`. That said, I did not read all your compose file in great detail. Postgres is it's own beast. I will edit my answer for postgres.

Comment: Compose creates a network named `default` for you automatically; you don't need to run `docker network create` or add `networks:` blocks.  You should in fact be able to call from one container to another with a URL like `https://recipemanagement-authserver:8080` (be aware of trouble with TLS certificate names needing to match the URL host name, though).  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation has more details on this.

Comment: Yes I tried this as well. You can see I’m actually doing it with my DB (which works as expected) but the urls don’t resolve for the auth env var

Comment: @DavidMaze That's a great link to the docs on the default network. Simple is better. My container-to-container and container-to-host configurations are fraught with five years of SO hacks and workarounds.

Comment: `host.docker.internal:127.0.0.1` doesn't work on linux (linux mint 21.2)